# Click button to select text

Tags: jquery

I've read many stackoverflow questions with people having the same problem as me but most fixes are deprecrated (jQuery).

I want to click a button to highlight a textarea for people to copy paste. Preferrable using jQuery for this solution.

```
<div class="profile">
  <textarea class="text">Hello!</textarea>
  <a href="#"><div class="button">Copy</div></a>
</div>
```

How can I make it so that when button is clicked it will .focus and .select textarea. I will be having multiple profile divs so It **must** be the one above the button. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c4aa189e/

I seem to have fixed it to use 
`$(this).prevAll('textarea:first').select().focus().click();` and by removing my `<a href="#">` infront of the button.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're after - the immediately preceding textarea gets focus and the text is selected.  This is using the latest version of jquery.

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  $(this).prevAll('textarea:first').focus().click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea class="profile" onclick="this.select()">123456</textarea>
<textarea class="profile" onclick="this.select()">ABCDEFG</textarea>
<br/>
<br/>
<button class="btn">CLICK ME</button>
<br>
<br>
<textarea class="profile" onclick="this.select()">UVWXYZ</textarea>
<br/>
<br/>
<button class="btn">CLICK ME</button>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, I've setup a fiddle, it might explain it a bit more; http://jsfiddle.net/c4aa189e/ . When the button is clicked, the textfield above needs to get highlighted. Thank you

Comment: I seem to have fixed it by removing the <a href="#"> infront of my button. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Yes, when you add the click function, the `<a>` tag is no longer required.